# How can I identify this microwave circuit?

Tags: integrated-circuit, microwave, coupler

I found this microwave circuit from [e-bay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/275507508884?hash=item402586f694:g:3uIAAOSwmMBjUWd7&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAAwOuoyZfharjig01jGAbgeCScw%2BPjd6Ydvl40Gf335mhEv6pT%2F1v6OS1G98cm4%2BGmcWE%2BA%2FgIyht1FRPjKLkIzPWI9wHPGaVvRVu%2ByteW1Ig86gh58nxzW04mE3AiHDUMPzZ52r4C6RHGClY5HDs%2F2V9qCDyw%2BhPhLUG7QBjhL6gLtvF3U5yw5sHVeDwxpLXLX2ZvLWOyu0tjNSx6mgzVQE8PN2bl9vaVjkL0gvG291E%2FhYL%2FczY%2FjvV%2FLMA56sox2Q%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR8Dvray_Yg) but cannot identify what this circuit is doing. I am asking this question since I found the same circuit from the sampling scope that I was tearing down in the lab. I guess this is some sort of a coupler or non-linear transmission line, but cannot confirm it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could help us by telling which scope it came from

Comment: It's listed as 'Agilent EE802C2 Microwave DIE'.  https://www.ebay.com/itm/275507508884

Comment: @vu2nan that is the link that I had in the original post.

Comment: @pipe it is from 86118A

Comment: @Emm386 Ok, probably too new to have good service manuals then